# page goto top when i click the jquery events

Tags: jquery

when i click the anchor tag that hide the div, i get bump to top of page although the div gets hidden. How do i make browser stay at same place when div gets hidden by clicking that link ? here is the code

```
< a id="Student" href="#">Click here to hide</a> 

$('#Student').click(function(){
    $('#divHide').hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default link behavior like this:

```
$('#Student').click(function(e){
  $('#divHide').hide('slow');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#Student').click(function(){
  $('#divHide').hide('slow');
  return false;
});
```

[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false;` will both prevent what the browser does by default which is going to the hash (`#`) for a location, causing a scroll to the top.  The difference between the two is that `return false` also kills the event, preventing it from bubbling as well.

Comment: in addition, `return false` will also trigger `stopPropagation()`

Comment: @jAndy - It doesn't *trigger* it exactly, but yes it has the same effect (actually *more* of an effect).

Comment: well, jQuery calls `preventDefault` + `stopPropagation` on the event object if `false` is returned from the handler.